# How to change a proportion of values in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to find out how to change the values in a data.frame based on specific proportions. This is an example of the values in the data.frame where class values (with different counts) are grouped by the field "id":

```
> head(pts)
     id   class
1    245   10
2    522   10
3    522   10
4    522   10
```

And this is an example of the proportions:

```
id  class   perc%
245   10    100
522   10    50
522   20    50
```

My objective is to be able to select the values for each "id" and change them according to the "perc%" field, e.g. if I have 100 values for id=522 then change 50 values to class=10 and then 50 values to class=20 (perc%=50).

I've tried subsetting the data.frame or making conditional selections but can't find a way to basically join the "perc%" with the counts of values per "id".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this with `data.table` maybe? `library(data.table);
dt <- setDT(pts)[, list(count = .N), by = .(id, class)][, perc := count*100/sum(count), by = id];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see better what you are trying to do now, this code may not be very elegant, but should get the job done. The "percentages" dataframe represents the second table you described, note that I am renaming "perc%" to be "perc"

```
colnames(df.percentages) <- c("id","class","perc")

p.check <- df.percentages %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(sum(perc))
colnames(p.check) <- c("id","sumperc")

not100 <- which(p.check$sumperc != 100)
if(length(not100) != 0)
{
  print(paste("ID",p.check$id[not100],"does not add up to 100%"))
}
rm(p.check)


ids <- unique(df.percentages$id)

for(i in 1:length(ids))
{
  print("")
  print(paste("Processing ID:",ids[i]))
  classes.to.reassign <- pts %>% filter(id == ids[i])
  if(nrow(classes.to.reassign) == 0)
  {
    print(paste("Could not find ID",ids[i],"pts dataframe!"))
    next
  }

  class.rows <- df.percentages %>% 
                filter(id == ids[i]) %>%
                mutate(rows = as.integer(round(nrow(classes.to.reassign) * (perc / 100))))

  if(nrow(classes.to.reassign) < nrow(class.rows))
  {
    print(paste("Cannot split", nrow(classes.to.reassign), "classes into", nrow(class.rows), "segments for ID:", ids[i]))
    next
  }

  if(sum(class.rows$rows) > nrow(classes.to.reassign))
    {class.rows$rows[nrow(class.rows)] <- class.rows$rows[nrow(class.rows)] + (nrow(classes.to.reassign) - sum(class.rows$rows))}
  else if(sum(class.rows$rows) < nrow(classes.to.reassign))
    {class.rows$rows[nrow(class.rows)] <- class.rows$rows[nrow(class.rows)] + (sum(class.rows$rows) - nrow(classes.to.reassign))}

  class.rows <- class.rows %>%
                mutate(cumrows = cumsum(as.integer(rows)))

  print(paste("Total rows for ID",ids[i],"=",nrow(classes.to.reassign)))

  cur.row <- 1
  for(c in 1:nrow(class.rows))
  {
    last.row <- class.rows$cumrow[c]
    print(paste("Assigning class",class.rows$class[c],"to rows",cur.row,"-",last.row))
    classes.to.reassign$class[cur.row:last.row] <- class.rows$class[c]
    cur.row <- last.row + 1
  }

  if(i == 1)
  {pts.new <- classes.to.reassign}
  else
  {pts.new <- rbind(pts.new, classes.to.reassign)}

  rm(classes.to.reassign, class.rows)

}

pts <- pts.new

View(pts)
```

Comment: Thanks again Matt. I had a go with a larger dataset (keeping all column names the same) and run your script, I got an error: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "class", value = 20) : replacement has 1 row, data has 0". Any ideas?

Comment: There is probably a remainder coming from the percentage calculation that is causing it to have an extra row. Try inserting this `if(last.row > nrow(classes.to.reassign))
{last.row <- nrow(classes.to.reassign)}` in between the `last.row <- class.rows$cumrow[c]` and `classes.to.reassign$class[cur.row:last.row] <- class.rows$class[c]` lines

Comment: I might try putting in a `print(paste("cur.row",cur.row,"last.row",lastrow))` in that same section. It may help narrow down where the error is happening.

Comment: I have the impression the error appears when the count of the values is an odd number and the assignment leads to decimals. Would that make sense?

Comment: It should be able to handle odd numbers without any issue. The only other way I received that error, is when one of the ids in the percentages dataframe does not exist within the pts dataframe, After the line `classes.to.reassign <- pts %>% filter(id == ids[i])`  try adding the line `if(nrow(classes.to.reassign) == 0){next}` This should catch if that ever happens and move to the next id.

Comment: It started working but stopped at this: Error in classes.to.reassign$class[cur.row:last.row] <- class.rows$class[c] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Comment: Without knowing your actual datasets, it's difficult to say what exactly is causing the issue. But if you add the lines `print("")
  print(paste("Processing ID:",ids[i]))
  print(paste("Total rows for ID",ids[i],"=",nrow(classes.to.reassign)))` above `cur.row <- 1` and add `print(paste("Assigning class",class.rows$class[c],"to rows",cur.row,"-",last.row))` after the line `last.row <- class.rows$cumrow[c]` It may help you narrow down where the issue is occurring and what might be causing it. I've placed the modified code in the answer as well.

Comment: I think I found what causes the problem: ids that have only 1 value but more than one proportion (<100%).

Comment: I've edited the answer to now include a check to make sure there are enough values available to be split into the entered percentages.